# How to pass property of Integer in React?

Tags: reactjs, constructor, integer, long-integer

I know in if string the way to write is

```
this.state ={event_email: ''}
```

but how if the value I need is integer?

```
this.state={id: //??}
```

Comment: you can use `id:0` or `id:null` in jsx, in typescript you can define `interface`

Answer (score 0):

Found in the documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { id: 0 };
}
```